# Visual Studio Code debugger does not stop at breakpoints with pytest-asyncio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, python-asyncio, pytest-asyncio

I have a python project that uses `pytest`. We have some functions that are async and therefore we need to have async tests. In this sense, we added the `pytest-asyncio` package as a dependency. Now, we can run our tests, but when we try to debug them using Visual Studio Code `Test Explorer` we came up with the fact that it doesn't stop on breakpoints.

I tried googling older posts bringing up this issue but couldn't find any. Does anyone know if this is a known issue or how I can solve it?

Basically, to replicate this you need to generate a python file with the following test:

```
import pytest

async def foo():
  hello = "123"
  print(hello)
  return hello

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_foo():
  result = await foo()
assert "123" == result
```

You first need to run `pip install pytest asyncio pytest-asyncio`, add some breakpoint on the `print(hello)` line and then run the tests with the VS Code python test explorer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Have you chosen `Debug Test` instead of `Run Test`?

Comment: doesn't work using unittest